# Unable to run shared memory program

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I have written the below programs as shared memory example. I want to write some message from the shared memory created in the write.c file and want display it in the read.c process from the same memory. But when I try to run the programs, I am getting the error message:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Tried but unable to find the error in my code.

**write.c file:**

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    key_t key=1235;
    int shm_id;
    void *shm;
    char *message = "hello";
    shm_id = shmget(key,10*sizeof(char),IPC_CREAT);
    shm = shmat(shm_id,NULL,NULL);
    sprintf(shm,"%s",message);
}
```

**read.c file:**

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    key_t key=1235;
    int shm_id;
    void *shm;
    char *message;
    message = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    shm_id = shmget(key,10*sizeof(char),NULL);
    shm = shmat(shm_id,NULL,NULL);
    if(shm == NULL)
    {
        printf("error");
    }
    sscanf(shm,"%s",message);
    printf("\n message = %s\n",message);
}
```

Comment: `if(shm == NULL)` shmat() returns a (void*)-1 on error, IIRC

Comment: @joop I did not get your hint.

Comment: @Jayesh do you have any idea what I need to fix in sprintf(shm,"%s",message);

Comment: `RETURN VALUE
       On  success  shmat() returns the address of the attached shared memory segment; on error (void *) -1 is returned, and errno is set to indicate the
       cause of the error.` (RTFM)

Comment: @joop okay then why I am unable to run it and getting Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the sprintf that is the problem. This is a permission problem, where you don't have permission to attach the segment you just created. When I run your "write" program as a normal user, shmat fails and returns -1, and then the sprintf of course crashes. shmat also sets errno to 13 ("Permission denied"). When I run it as root, it works.

Try this instead (and with a new key):

```
shm_id = shmget(key, 10*sizeof(char), IPC_CREAT | 0777);
```

The flags 0777 are the permissions on the segment, similar to the permissions on a file.

Comment: @user3751012: It works for me when I try it. Did you remember to use a new key?

Answer (score 0):

```
By tracking the error using printf statement ,

main() {

 key_t key=1235;
 int shm_id;
 void *shm;
 char *message = "hello";
 shm_id = shmget(key,10*sizeof(char),IPC_CREAT);
 printf("hello 1\n");
 shm = shmat(shm_id,NULL,NULL);
 printf("hello 2\n");
 sprintf(shm,"%s",message);
 printf("hello 3\n");

}

I explored that it is giving segmentation fault after executing sprint, so look for the arguments that you passed to function .
Similar is the case for sscanf in read.c
```

Comment: I have found this before a long time. But not getting what is the exact problem. However, thanks.

Comment: The reason it fails in sprintf is because the shmat call failed, and the shm pointer is invalid. The sprintf call itself is okay.

Comment: yes, I tried error handling with,  if(shm == (char*)-1) perror("shmat"); it prints permission denied.